# Selecting a drop down option

Tags: selenium, mobile, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm simulating a mobile phone browser and tryng to select a dropdown item.
I'm using a css selector to find the combobox, when I check that css selector in the developers tool is found but not in my code

```
List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By
            .cssSelector(".show-deals-wrapper select"));

    for (WebElement element : linkElements) {

        if (element.isDisplayed()
                && ("Pay Monthly").equals(element.getText())) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }

    }
```

The web is https://www.o2.co.uk/shop in mobile version. 
I'm really new in Selenium, learning bit a bit. Sorry if the question is so easy.

Many thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: in ur website which dropdow item u want to select?

Comment: When you go to the webpage in a **mobile version** , you get the tabs "apple" "paymonthly" "Pay&go" "ipad" "Accessories" as a dropdown. That is the one I want to use

Comment: i saw that there is a pop up message shown when ur website is loaded . first remove that and than first click on that. After showing all the drop down menu, than use ur code.....actually i can give u detail code if this is in not in mobile version.

Comment: ur code seems ok but check cssSelector(".show-deals-wrapper select")) is the correct and no need to use element.isDisplayed() when u click on that dropdown.   please let me know what happens.

Comment: Actually I'm trying also in a **web version** but I'm getting "element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" . I tried different ways, using select component, using just webelement, clicking directly in the item I want to select.. but no way.. The combobox is located in [link] (https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/tariff/samsung/galaxy-s7/?productId=f06174ad-4c08-4c8e-80a5-5989e9e92cf1&planId=&contractType=paymonthly) .That is after select a phone and click in view tariff button. Many thanks in advance

Comment: sorry....there is no "view tariff"  i found ... it will be helpful if u attach an image with which drop down u want to click.

Comment: Sorry, just click the url, and the only dropdown that there is in that page ( "Sort Tariff" )

Comment: sorry for my late reply.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to make the element visible first. then do your job as it is and finally make that element invisible again. see the code portion below:

```
            JavascriptExecutor js    = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;                
            js.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').style.display='block'");
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(elementID));
            select.selectByIndex(pos);
            js.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').style.display='none'");
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Many many thanks, It works. My only question is, why is necessary to enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle selects with webdriver.  I hope this helps.  Also I am using python

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.show-deals-wrapper.select')).select_by_visible_text("Pay Monthly")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using select in java , but it getting "element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Comment: how are the items in the select drop down populated?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, finally I get to do that with the selected above solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

u can aslo do like below:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)", "");

driver.findElement(By.id("dataFilterSelectSelectBoxItArrowContainer")).click();

List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By
        .cssSelector(" #dataFilterSelectSelectBoxItOptions>li>a"));

System.out.println("size is "+linkElements.size());
for (WebElement element : linkElements) {

    System.out.println("size is "+element.getText());

    if (("ur text").equals(element.getText())) {
        element.click();
        break;
    }

}
```

this will click on what sort tariff u want.